# Filter wrong characters from android package name using regex

Tags: android, regex, android-manifest

I want to filter wrong characters from a string (and replace them with empty string later). I tried making my own regex expression but I have not succeeded to make it fully working. I need JavaScript support.

Desired effect: `com.12%example%.5a5pp` => `com.example.a5pp` (regex matches: `[1,2,%,%,5]`).

You can find package name requirements [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package):

> A full Java-language-style package name for the Android application. The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more familiar with Ruby myself, but I believe Android apps are written in Java, and Java can do `(?<)` look-behinds. On those assumptions, this regex will match any incorrect character:

```
/[^\w.]|(?<=^|\.)[^A-Za-z]+/g
```

You can plug this into your 'replace' method to replace any match with an empty string.

([Regex 101](https://regex101.com) is a good place to find the meaning of each component of a regex.)

---

[Update] For JavaScript, which doesn't support look-behinds, you'd probably have to capture the dot (if there is one) in a group to be able to put it back:

```
/[^\w.]|(^|\.)[^A-Za-z]+/g
```

Instead of an empty string, you would replace this with `'$1'` (which represents the captured dot).

Comment: I didn't say it earlier but I use JavaScipt and this "proceeded by" operator is not working there.

Comment: Well, that changes things. I'll update shortly with something that works for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @PJSCopeland! I've tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/eS5aA3/1) and it seems to not match `_` characters on the start of the string (or after a dot).

Comment: Ah, it looks like `[^A-z]` *includes* `_`, possibly because it falls between `Z` and `a` in terms of its character code. Try `[^A-Za-z]` instead. (I've updated my answer to reflect this.)